# “upskill your mind”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

First question:
Does the phrase “upskill your mind” make natural and perfect sense in English? What I am going to convey by this phrase (as sn article title) is “improve and enhance your own mental skills”.
However, it is ok if it has a little edge or is slightly uncommon in order to create a little fraction and grab some attention, but not to the degree that it seems ‘an obviously wrong usage of the word “upskill”’.

Second question:
is “upskill” a verb whose meaning would be fully understood by even uneducated native Speakers of English? (the audience of the article are the general public)

Comment: Your questions would likely fare better on our sister site for [ell.se].

Answer (score 2):

The word "upskill" is management-science jargon - meaning to "advance the skills of a person, department or institution" (my definition).

There is no set idiomatic phrase "upskill your mind" - but its meaning seems quite obvious.

Comment: thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

While the phrase "upskill your mind" does make sense, the word is very uncommon and until now I've never heard it used in a sentence. As such I don't think many people know what the word means and likely wouldn't understand the title of the article.

Comment: what about “skill up your mind”?  does the same apply to this?

Comment: "skill up your mind" doesn't read very well, the phrase "level up your mind" might suit your needs better.

Comment: Please capitalise conventionally if you wish your answers to look credible.

Comment: Even though people may not have heard the term before, it's intent will be immediately obvious to any native English speakers.

Comment: thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

The word "upskill" is recent jargon, used in personal development and management science, usually when selling  something to someone. It brands the speaker as a hukster. Alsomst any writing or speech would be improed by not using it. ising "skill" as a verb to mean "learn a skill" is also jargon, and should be avoided.